# Caching behavior with location.reload() is different between browsers

Tags: javascript, browser-cache

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload) says `location.reload()` takes one optional argument.

> **forcedReload**
>
> Is a Boolean flag, which, when it is true, causes the page to always be reloaded from the server. If it is false or not specified, the browser may reload the page from its cache.

But this argument doesn't work in IE and Chrome.

Below table shows what header sent to the server (`no-cache` means `Pragma: no-cache`):

```
+---------------+----------+-------------------+-------------------+
|               |   IE11   |     Firefox47     |      Chrome54     |
+---------------+----------+-------------------+-------------------+
| reload(false) | no-cache | If-Modified-Since | If-Modified-Since |
+---------------+----------+-------------------+-------------------+
| reload(true)  | no-cache | no-cache          | If-Modified-Since |
+---------------+----------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

IE and Chrome sends different caching headers, not only ignores `forcedReload` argument.

Also, [W3C Spec of this method](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#dom-location-reload) doesn't seem to mention about caching.

So my question is...

- What should I expect from `location.reload()` about caching?
- Is there any (standardization) discussion about this?